# Transaction not received?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-verification

Can someone help me? i did my first transaction

From ID : 3FxvvRt1wpTHzN8xYVBXMsrGB6aTSrndBQ

To ID: 3LSGTkzC62tgTALSGHF7Ztw1dPF5Vyg38B

The adresses are right, not fault to find?

Thanks

Comment: seems to be confirmed , but no money arrived yet..

Comment: @jensss: What software are you using for the receiving wallet? Is it possible that the receiving wallet is still synchronizing with the network's state?

Comment: Also, the transaction you reference seems to be on the Bitcoin network, but you tagged this question as "Bitcoin-cash". Is it possible that you were using a Bitcoin Cash (which is another cryptocurrency) wallet and it is looking for the transaction on the wrong network?